# vacuum chamber and impact on various liquids

Tags: vacuum

I am hoping to do an experiment on "the impact of a vacuum chamber on various liquids".  What liquids would be the most interesting? Water, coffee, soda, gatorade? Would carbonated versus non carbonated make a large difference? I would like to know at what level of pressure they would boil? Do you have any suggestions or feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Water, coffee, and Gatorade are basically the same (water), but carbonated water might be interesting. For comparison, you might want to find a liquid (mostly) not based on water, like rubbing alcohol. Also, your liquids might not boil at all. You’d have to check a phase diagram.